# PersistenceException:ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"

Tags: java, encryption, password-encryption

I am working on *PostgreSQL* and getting below error during update statement execution from java code.

```
ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

The code snippet for password encrption is :

```
StringBuilder encryptionKey = new StringBuilder().append(newPassword).append(userEmail).append(userEmail).append(userEmail);
AdvancedEncryptionStandard aes = new AdvancedEncryptionStandard(encryptionKey.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
newEncryptedPwd =  new String(aes.encrypt(newPassword.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
EntityManager em = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager(schemaName);
EntityManagerUtil.beginTransaction(schemaName);
Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE User um SET um.password=:newPassword WHERE um.loginId=:userID");
query.setParameter("userID", userName);
query.setParameter("newPassword", newEncryptedPwd);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Encrypt function is as below:

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText) throws Exception
    {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key,0,16,'AES');
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    }
public AdvancedEncryptionStandard(byte[] key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }
```

I have checked `client_encoding` by `show client_encoding` command and it is showing UTF-8.

Can someone give me pointer on resolving this issue? I have gone through the suggestions provided in other threads but none helped.

Answer (score 0):

0 actually is invalid UTF8. UTF8 contains æ, it contains ™, but none of what it contains has code point 0.

Your problem is that you're trying to store arbitrary binary data as though it were UTF8-encoded text. Don't. If you encrypt something, the encryption will have hidden its nature (that's *the job description* for encryption) so it was an integer, you no longer can store it in an `integer` column, it if was text you no longer can store it in a `text` column. What you have is just [an array of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34486931/fnord).