# population csv file into sql

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

```
COPY population 
FROM '/Users/chittampalliyashaswini/Documents/population.csv'
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I tried running this same command. I moved the population csv to the my documents folder.

This is the result I am getting.

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
CONTEXT:  COPY population, line 1
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
SQL state: 22021
Context: COPY population, line 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres error on insert - ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347646/postgres-error-on-insert-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0x0)

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no simple answer to this question.

As given [here](http://dbaspot.com/postgresql/428516-general-invalid-byte-sequence-restore.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347646/postgres-error-on-insert-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0x0), this basically is about PostgreSQL's incapability to store a data in the column that you want it to. Ideally you should solve this by going back to the source, and change *every* instance of such a character and then take a re-dump and use that to restore the target DB once again.

The URLs given above, both give ways to do this, albeit agreeably they aren't very convenient.