# Unable to trim empty space in pyspark dataframe

Tags: data-cleaning, pyspark, data-ingestion

While loading data from Oracle and writing to PostgreSQL facing weird issue. Unable to write string with space to postgres. Facing below issue

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO xyz("col1","col2") VALUES ('7643'::numeric,'xyz/xyz xyzxy xyz/xyz xyzxy ') was aborted: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch
```

So trying to trim col in dataframe but that is not working. Before and after trimming data is same.

```
data= data.withColumn("trimmed", trim(col("col2")))
```

Am very new to pyspark and data cleaning, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the trim is working just fine. The `trim` function just removes spaces from both ends of the stream. And actually your problem is not that. The issue is that Postgres doesn't accept the NULL character (i.e. `0x00`, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347646/postgres-error-on-insert-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0x0)), and it looks like you have some in your `col2`. Try cleaning those first with something like:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col
data = data.withColumn("col2", regexp_replace(col("col2"), "\u0000", ""))
```

Comment: It worked. I have used dataframe.replace..not sure why it didn't work. Need to check what it does.

Comment: Maybe you can accept this answer then? :)

Comment: Already accepted. But what I couldn't get is the column value for which this error is coming is not null. It just has some empty space at the end. Any idea on that ?