# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, exception, ldap

I am getting this exception

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(SqlExceptionHelper.java:142) - ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
  Where: unnamed portal parameter $2
```

In the method below, authentication is done with ldap. If an incorrect username or password or connection exception occurs, one of the following exceptions will be caught.

```
@Override
public ResponseResource login(DomainLoginRequestDto requestDto) {
    LOG.info("username : " + requestDto.getUsername() + " type : " + requestDto.getType());
    String fullName = null;
    try {
        Map<String, String> authenticate = ldapUtility.authenticate(requestDto.getUsername(), requestDto.getPassword());
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : authenticate.entrySet()) {
            fullName = entry.getValue();
        }
        ResponseEntity<ResponseResource> responseDto = new ResponseEntity<>(new SuccessResponseResource(SUCCESS_OPERATION.getMessage(), SUCCESS_OPERATION.getCode(), fullName), HttpStatus.OK);

        saveResponse(requestDto.getUsername(), requestDto.getType(), responseDto, null);
        return responseDto.getBody();
    } catch (CommunicationException connect) {
        System.out.println(connect.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println(connect.getMessage());
        System.out.println(connect.getExplanation());
        LOG.error("wrong connection " + connect.toString());
        ResponseEntity<ResponseResource> responseDto = new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponseResource(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT.getMessage(), CONNECTION_TIMEOUT.getCode()), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        saveResponse(requestDto.getUsername(), requestDto.getType(), responseDto, connect);
        return responseDto.getBody();
    } catch (NamingException namingException) {
        LOG.error("invalid username or password " + namingException.toString());
        ResponseEntity<ResponseResource> responseDto = new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponseResource(WRONG_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD.getMessage(), WRONG_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD.getCode()), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        saveResponse(requestDto.getUsername(), requestDto.getType(), responseDto, namingException);
        return responseDto.getBody();
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is this. I send the exceptions to the method below and convert the exception to String and add it to my entity class.

```
    private void saveResponse(String username, String type, ResponseEntity<ResponseResource> responseDto, Exception e) {
        DomainLogin domainLogin = new DomainLogin();
        domainLogin.setUsername(username);
        domainLogin.setType(type);
        domainLogin.setRequest(username + " , " + type);
        if (responseDto.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR ||
                responseDto.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        ) {
    //here are I am sendinh exception message with ldapResponse field.
            domainLogin.setLdapResponse(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            domainLogin.setStatusMessage(Objects.requireNonNull(responseDto.getBody()).getMessage());
            domainLogin.setStatusCode(responseDto.getBody().getCode());
//I am getting exception in this line
            this.domainLoginRepository.save(domainLogin);
        }
        if (responseDto.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            domainLogin.setStatusMessage(Objects.requireNonNull(responseDto.getBody()).getMessage());
            domainLogin.setStatusCode(responseDto.getBody().getCode());
            this.domainLoginRepository.save(domainLogin);
        }
    }
```

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class DomainLogin {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String type;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String request;

    private String ldapResponse;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String statusMessage;

    private int statusCode;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private Date createdDate;

    @PrePersist
    public void persist() {
        setCreatedDate(new Date());
    }

}
```

But I am getting the following exception when the `save` operation occurs.

```
12-2021-27 [WARN ] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(SqlExceptionHelper.java:137) - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22021
12-2021-27 [ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(SqlExceptionHelper.java:142) - ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
  Where: unnamed portal parameter $2
12-2021-27 [ERROR] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:175) - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
  Where: unnamed portal parameter $2
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3298) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3825) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.save(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at az.expressbank.ldap.service.impl.DomainLoginServiceImpl.saveResponse(DomainLoginServiceImpl.java:81) ~[classes/:?]
    at az.expressbank.ldap.service.impl.DomainLoginServiceImpl.login(DomainLoginServiceImpl.java:65) ~[classes/:?]
    at az.expressbank.ldap.controller.DomainLoginController.login(DomainLoginController.java:23) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

I researched some stuff and it says there like this.

```
 PostgreSQL doesn't support storing NULL (\0x00) characters in text fields (this is obviously different from the database NULL value, which is fully supported).
```

But the part I don't understand is which value I am getting null here? I know when I debug that my Entity class places my exception message in the ldapResponse variable.

Comment: This link helpmed me to solve problem. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347646/postgres-error-on-insert-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0x0/45810272](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347646/postgres-error-on-insert-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0x0/45810272)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using this code.

```
String exceptionMessage = exception.getLocalizedMessage().replaceAll("\u0000", "");
```

References from here. [Postgres error on insert - ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347646/postgres-error-on-insert-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0x0/45810272)

Comment: The answer looks good to me but I would also welcome a short explanation very much.