# PostgreSQL - Error: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Tags: database, postgresql, utf-8, postgresql-9.5

Currently, we are facing an issue while inserting a record in PostgresSQL. My data-type is of type TEXT. It throws an error saying **Error: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00**.

The data that we are trying to insert contains RTF text which contains text, image followed by again text. We also made sure there are no null values passed or inserted.

We are using **PostgresSQL **version 9.6 and 12 with an encoding set as UTF-8.

Any help would be appreciated.

The RTF data with text and images (contains special characters) should insert into PostgresSQL without any issues. Also, the data type should be of type TEXT.

Comment: are you trying to save binary data in a text field? probably you need to encode it with something like uuencode.

Comment: The name is [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), not PostresSQL.

Comment: *We also made sure there are no null values passed or inserted.* You clearly didn't do a good job when you made sure. What do you think 0x00 is other than a null value? An image is not text, it's binary, and you can't store it in a text field in any database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres error on insert - ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347646/postgres-error-on-insert-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0x0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store a zero byte as part of a text string in PostgreSQL. You have two options:

- remove this character from the input string if it is not required
- use data type `bytea`, which is suitable for binary data

If you want to stick with `text`, you should also figure out what the encoding of the file is.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use `text` type, you could save it base64 encoded.

There is a space overhead in the DB of about 30% over the raw data and a modest amount of CPU in your app code to encode/decode it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `decode` function to insert binary values, including hex 0, into a `text` column:

```
postgres=# create table jos(foo text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into jos values('foo'||decode('00', 'hex')||'bar');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from jos;
     foo
------------------
 \x666f6f00626172
(1 row)
```