# Saving the record containing escaping pattern with Prisma ORM to PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prisma

From the 3-d party API I'm receiving the item object with field like this:

```
  title: 'String part... other part\x00. End part ',
```

which contains escaping pattern "\x00".

When I'm trying to save record with that kind of fields included, I'm having the error error:

```
Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Error { kind: Db, cause: Some(DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState(E22021), message: "invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0x00", detail: None, hint: None, position: None, where_: Some("unnamed portal parameter $8"), schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("mbutils.c"), line: Some(1665), routine: Some("report_invalid_encoding")
```

But I still need to save the data as it is.

Comment: Would you add the query to your post please?

Comment: Does [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347646/postgres-error-on-insert-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0x0) helps?